# React Antd dropdown throws if menu is dynamic

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to get an Antd dropdown based on an array but it keeps failing with **Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.**

I have seen the other threads about it but I am confused because my menu works if the data is static: Here's a snippet

```
  var items = [
    {
      key: '0',
      label:  'item0',
    },
    {
      key: '1',
      label:  'item1',
    }
  ];
  
  var items2 = []
  for (let item of items) items2.push({key: items2.length.toString(), label: item.label})
  
  console.log(items, items2, JSON.stringify(items), JSON.stringify(items2), JSON.stringify(items) === JSON.stringify(items2) )
  
  return (<>
    <Dropdown menu={{ items }} trigger={['click']}>
      <a onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
        {name} <DownOutlined />
      </a>
    </Dropdown>
    <Dropdown menu={{ items2 }} trigger={['click']}>
      <a onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
        {name} <DownOutlined />
      </a>
    </Dropdown>
  </>)
```

As expected, items and items2 are the same by construction, and `JSON.stringify(items) === JSON.stringify(items2) )` is `true`

However, clicking on the first dropdown with items works, while clicking on the second one throws.

How can I solve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first works only by coincidence! because the `variable` name is *items* and since you have to specify the `property` name which is also *items* it works so

```
{{items}}
```

is in fact :

```
{{items:items}}
```

for the second one you should mention the `property` *items* because you have a differently named `variable`

```
{{items:items2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `menu={{ items2 }}` to `menu={{ items: items2 }}` 
the menu attribute must have the items property 
I hope it help

Answer (score 1):

You should write it like this

```
<Dropdown menu={{ items: items2 }} trigger={["click"]}>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W88sR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se79k.png)